# Can't run DB migration on PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, pg

I've just changed from sqlite3 to PG and after creating a database via pgAdmin and trying to run a migration, I run into the following, which I don't understand.

```
Pawel:bodb pawel$ rake db:create
DEPRECATION WARNING: Rake tasks in /Users/pawel/Ruby/apps/bodb/vendor/plugins/google_charts_on_rails/tasks/google_charts_on_rails_tasks.rake are deprecated. Use lib/tasks instead. (called from /Users/pawel/Ruby/apps/bodb/Rakefile:7)

firstdb already exists
Pawel:bodb pawel$ rake db:migrate
DEPRECATION WARNING: Rake tasks in /Users/pawel/Ruby/apps/bodb/vendor/plugins/google_charts_on_rails/tasks/google_charts_on_rails_tasks.rake are deprecated. Use lib/tasks instead. (called from /Users/pawel/Ruby/apps/bodb/Rakefile:7)
==  AddLikesToUsers: migrating ================================================
-- add_column(:Users, :likes, :string)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PGError: ERROR:  relation "Users" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "Users" ADD COLUMN "likes" character varying(255)

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about the warnings, but the error message says:

> relation "Users" does not exist

Maybe you are using upper case "Users", where the table's name is `users`? [Identifiers in PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html) are case insensitive as long as they are not double-quoted.

Comment: Rails is creating all my tables and schema.rb shows them as lower case so can't be that.

Comment: @Simpleton: if they **are** lower case, then this **is** the problem. The query reads `ALTER "Users"`, not `ALTER users` or `ALTER Users`.

Comment: @Simpleton: `add_column(:Users, :likes, :string)` isn't right, it should be `add_column(:users, :likes, :string)` so Erwin is on the right track.

Comment: Correct. That did seem to be the problem in the "likes" migration. Thanks

Comment: what about this error , can it be solved ?
`== AddColumn1: migrating ===================================================== -- add_column(:users, :first_name, :string) rake aborted! An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled: PG::Error: ERROR: relation "users" does not exist`

Answer (score 1):

It appear that the migration assumes that an Users table already exists which is not the case with a completely new PostgreSQL database...

Did you forget to add some start schema to the database?

Comment: Perhaps, nothing of the sort came up in the guides.

Comment: Ah, I can read from the other answer that you took out something from the migration output - it looked like AddLikesToUsers was the first migration you ran :-)

Comment: Yep, small things. Thanks though.